# What's wrong with this if statement?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

If this receives "ffff", it immediately resolves to true and displays the message box. The way I'm reading this is "if the text, starting at index (which initializes at zero earlier in the code) and going for a distance of 1 (meaning it only evaluates this single letter) is not either A-Z or a-z, then show this message box. Otherwise, exit this if-statement"

Why is that not what's actually happening?

```
If (txtPartNum.Text.Substring(index, 1) IsNot "[A-Z]" OrElse txtPartNum.Text.Substring(index, 1) IsNot "[a-z]") Then
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Part number must contain two numbers followed by two letters. first")
                blnValid = False
End If
```

Edit: I tried switching to this, and I'm not getting any luck with this, either

```
If (txtPartNum.Text.Substring(index, 1) Like "[!A-Z]" OrElse txtPartNum.Text.Substring(index, 1) Like "[!a-z]") Then
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Part number must contain two numbers followed by two letters. first")
                blnValid = False
End If
```

Edit 2: I made a string to hold txtPartNum.Text.Substring(index, 1), and verified that it is receiving the first letter in the textbox. I also tried removing the "!" in the character pattern, and that had no effect on whether or not it resolved true - it came up as true each time.

Comment: Because you're comparing strings ; not matching some kind of pattern ; it could actually be a nice idea to use a MaskedTextBox to enforce input rules

Comment: `IsNot` is not going to do pattern testing for you if that it what you are up to. use RegEx or `Char.IsLetter(txtPartNum.Text(0))`

Comment: It appears that you have confused the [IsNot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3bat82c.aspx) operator with the [Like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) operator.

Comment: @Plutonix I'm confused. What's the point of "IsNot" if it's not to find out if something "is not equal to" something else?

Comment: @AndrewMorton if I use "like" and change the [A-Z] to [!A-Z], it still resolves true when receiving "ffff" and "FFFF"

Comment: IsNot means "is not equal to" but for object reference ; and even then you don't want a "is not equal to" but rather a "don't match that pattern"

Comment: 1 character from a textbox is never going to "be equal to" the many chars in `[A-Z]`

Comment: That's not what msdn says - their example says the following statement returns true:  testCheck = "F" Like "[A-Z]". [A-Z] is a pattern.

Comment: `IsNot` <> `Like`

Comment: use a [MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx) with `"00LL"` as mask it'll ease your life a lot

Comment: I think "[!A-Z]" does not mean "not a character" but rather "exclamation mark or a character". Take the ! out of there and use a "Not Like" instead.

Comment: @CrushaK.Rool [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) begs to differ

Comment: The problem is also related to the code for the loop that you have not shown to us. If the code examines the first two characters then it has to check for digits, when it examines the third and fourth digits is has to check for letters.

Comment: I hadn't gotten to the bit about the digits yet - I was just trying to figure out why this if statement wasn't working. If I can get that, then I can easily handle the next part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have a simple pattern which the input must comply with, you can use a *regular expression*.

```
Dim textToLookAt = txtPartNum.Text
If Not (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textToLookAt, "^[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{2}")) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Error: Part number must contain two numbers followed by two letters. first")
    blnValid = False
End If
```

The `^` means the start of the line. The `[0-9]` means characters in the range "0" to "9". The `{2}` means exactly two of the previous item - in this case `[0-9]`. `[A-Za-z]` means characters in those ranges. There is nothing to tell the regex that the line must finish there, so any characters after the two digits and two letters are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure the rule you are checking against. It looks like you are trying to validate whether or not a part number starts with two digits following by two characters. Here is an example, but obviously change it accordingly to the rule that you wish to enforce.

```
If txtPartNum.Text LIKE "##??" = False Then
      MessageBox.Show("Error: Part number must contain two numbers followed by two letters.")
      blnValid = False
End If
```

If the part number is longer than 4, then check for `"##??*"`